# Pandas: Make xth next row a column

Tags: python, pandas, shift

We have following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John', 'Max', 'Ethan', 'Karen', 'Carl', 'Jenny']})
```

df:

```
   name
0  John
1  Max
2  Ethan
3  Caren
4  Carl
5  Jenny
6  Claudia
   ...
```

For each row, I like to:

- Add the + n-th row content in a new column
- Write into + n-th row the content of the upper one

**With rolling 0: (next row)**

```
   name   name_2  
0  John   Max
1  Max    John     
2  Ethan  Caren
3  Caren  Ethan
4  Carl   Jenny
5  Jenny  Carl
6  Claudia Whoever
   ...
```

**With rolling 1 (next row + 1):**

```
   name    name_2
0  John    Ethan
1  Max     Caren
2  Ethan   John
3  Caren   Max
4  Carl    Claudia
5  Jenny   Whoever
6  Claudia Carl
...
```

**Any idea how to solve this at best?** In the real dataset, there is not just name, but actually 5 columns.

Comment: can you explain the next row+1 output a bit in the question body?

Comment: Why are you doing that in the first place? Maybe there is an easier way for you to solve your actual underlying problem better!

Comment: Well, here's the problem: I have a long list of contacts. Over the next weeks, I need to create a couple of pairings, but the pairings are not allow to repeat. So randomisation would be easy. In between, it can happen that new entries are added to the list. I thought this would be trivial, but apparently...

Comment: Maybe one solution would be to in fact randomise, store the matches as unique id, and then in the next run let randomise everything until there's no match of unique id. It just feels a bit of clumsy. It would be so much better to let the list shift by a number to do the task.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you note that you want to create pairings that do not repeat. These are **combinations**. Hence simpler way is to generate valid **combinations** using `itertools.combinations()`

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""   name
0  John
1  Max
2  Ethan
3  Caren
4  Carl
5  Jenny
6  Claudia"""),sep="\s+")

import itertools

pd.DataFrame(itertools.combinations(df.name.to_list(),2), columns=["name","name_2"])
```

|  | name | name_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | Max |
| 1 | John | Ethan |
| 2 | John | Caren |
| 3 | John | Carl |
| 4 | John | Jenny |
| 5 | John | Claudia |
| 6 | Max | Ethan |
| 7 | Max | Caren |
| 8 | Max | Carl |
| 9 | Max | Jenny |
| 10 | Max | Claudia |
| 11 | Ethan | Caren |
| 12 | Ethan | Carl |
| 13 | Ethan | Jenny |
| 14 | Ethan | Claudia |
| 15 | Caren | Carl |
| 16 | Caren | Jenny |
| 17 | Caren | Claudia |
| 18 | Carl | Jenny |
| 19 | Carl | Claudia |
| 20 | Jenny | Claudia |